# What is "x Us" in a contactor coil specification?

Tags: coil, specifications, contactor

I have a data sheet that gives the coil pickup voltage as "0.85…1.1 x Us] and coil dropout voltage as "0.3…0.6 x Us".

I am assuming that Us refers to the nominal or specified coil voltage, but why is it "Us"?

Thanks

Comment: U is commonly used as as symbol for voltage on German schematics ... what make is the contactor?

Comment: @BrianDrummond [Here](http://cmsapps.sea.siemens.com/controls/icc/06IndControl_%20pdfs/06IC_02/02_035.pdf) is a Siemens contactor spec. It uses exactly that nomenclature.

Comment: The data sheet I have is from Rockwell (Allen-Bradley).

Answer (score 3):

Subscript S in \$U_S\$ symbol stands for German word **die Spule** which means **the coil**. So \$U_S\$ is the **coil voltage**.